Does the fail back only apply when failover happens to a non preferred node?
I'm trying to understand the failback setting.
Suppose I have 3 nodes in cluster (FCI):

Node 1 and 2 are preferred owners.
Node 1, 2 and 3 are possible owners.

Failover preference will be between node 1 and 2. And if both are down then failover happens to node 3. Now, when either node 1 or 2 are back online, then failback happens to one of them (based on order).
Another example is - suppose if I have 2 node cluster (FCI):

Node 1 is preferred owner.
Node 1 and 2 are possible owners.

Failover preference is node 1. If node 1 goes down, then there is failover to node 2. Now if node 1 is back online, then failback happens to node 1.
So does this mean that the fail back checkmark only applies when failover happens to a non preferred node?
Therefore, the setting is irrelevant when failover happens to one of the preferred nodes or if all the nodes are in preferred owners list?


So does this mean that the fail back checkmark only applies when failover happens to a non preferred node?
It applies to even failovers that happen to another preferred node. If you have more than one preferred node, they are ordered starting from the top. See the description of preferred node.

Therefore, the setting is irrelevant when failover happens to one of the preferred nodes or if all the nodes are in preferred owners list?
It is still relevant. It will try to failover from the most preferred to the least preferred node.
